# why L2 cache utilization is low even though L2 cache hit rate is about 93% in cuda?

Tags: caching, cuda, gpu

I'm doing expriments by using cuda.

I thought that if L2 cache hit ratio is high, performance will increase.

However, from nvprof, L2 cache utilization is low even though L2 cache hit rate is about 93%.

Why this happens? Are there examples that make it happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are different things. You can look for data in L2 cache infrequently, yet when you do so find that L2 almost always contains the data you are looking for.

In fact, this is a combination that is quite likely to go together, because low utilization means useful data is less likely to get evicted from the cache.

Answer (score 4):

L2 utilization and hit rate are orthogonal concepts.

L2 utilization % measures how many operations (reads/writes/atomics) the L2 cache performed, compared to its peak performance.  You can alternatively think of this as a proxy for "how much L2 bandwidth did I use" given there is a fixed bandwidth between L1 and L2 on a given GPU.  Note, this metric is not measuring the % of L2 capacity used.  (to simplify, in the diagram below, think of it as measuring the throughput of arrows next to the red dots)

L2 cache hit rate measures when an L1 miss occurs, how often was it found in L2.  (in the diagram, think of L2 cache tags at the green X)

*Original diagram from [Dissecting the NVidia Turing T4 GPU via Microbenchmarking](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.07486.pdf)*
[image]

Hypothetically:

- Some CUDA kernel could read a single L1 cacheline (128B) per SM once, incurring a single L2 read that always hits.  The L2 utilization would be ~0%, with L2 hit-rate of 100%.
- A different CUDA kernel could achieve ~100% L2 utilization and 100% L2 hit-rate, by performing tons of loads that either miss in L1, or were ["cache global" loads](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#data-movement-and-conversion-instructions), where the set of accessed addresses fit within the size of the L2.
- Yet another CUDA kernel could achieve high L2 utilization and low L2 hit-rate, by performing tons of loads that either miss in L1, or were ["cache global" loads](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#data-movement-and-conversion-instructions) that are scattered throughout a Gigabyte sized buffer (i.e. that don't all fit simultaneously in L2).

See also

- The [tables of metrics in the CUDA Toolkit Profiler documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#metrics-reference-7x).
- [Dissecting the NVidia Turing T4 GPU via Microbenchmarking](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.07486.pdf)
- [Dissecting the NVIDIA Volta GPU Architecture via Microbenchmarking](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.06826.pdf)